# Apache seems to remove slash from cgi-bin url

Tags: apache-2.2, vps

We have a 1and1 vps running centos which is behaving strangely when we try to post/get to the cgi-bin.

We have a directory called Monitor under the cgi-bin so to hit a perl script inside it we would call 
`https://example.co.uk/cgi-bin/Monitor/perlscript.pl`

however this returns an error as Apache looks for the file in `cgi-binMonitor` not `cgi-bin/Monitor`. If we create a directory called `cgi-binMonitor` and put the script in there it runs fine when called with the above url.

The httpd.conf file has the following:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

#
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The actual cgi-bin is not at `/var/www/cgi-bin` but `/var/www/vhosts/default/cgi-bin`

Any ideas whats causing this strange behaviour, whilst we have a poor solution of creating a `cgi-binMonitor` directory I'd rather fix it properly.

Comment: Why do you have quote marks around the actual path? And why does your posted content not match the path you say you're using?

Comment: Maybe try ScriptAliasMatch instead for more control over the replacement?  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#scriptaliasmatch

Comment: @JennyD mostly because I don't know what I'm doing! The quotes were not added by me but auto generated I guess. Regarding the path not matching I've tried with it matching the exact path but the result was the same, I've now set up another vhost (rather than using the default and now nothing works so I guess thats progress)..

Comment: @cxw thanks for the suggestion I've managed to hose the whole thing at the moment I'll try it once I get the new vhost working